# Using the SteamWebAPI to send a tradeoffer?

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

How can I send a trade offer via the Steam Web API or IEconService? I have been searching for ages but can't come up with any information on if it's possible )or not possible) to send tradeoffers with the Steam Web API.

If I cannot send tradeoffers via the Web API, what would be the most convenient way of sending them from a web server (preferably without Node.js, like Node-Steam).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'm going to use a C# Steam Bot on a VPS and use a MySQL database for the queue.

Source: http://www.reddit.com/r/SteamBot/comments/1uehje/web_integration/cehqxpl